# Jenkins create only one database when django settings have two

Tags: django, jenkins

Django settings file have details of 2 databases. While running the tests from Django test, it creates 2 databases before running the tests.

But the same is executed in Jenkins, it says "Creating test database for alias 'default'..." then start executing the tests. This results in the failure of tests where the second db is mentioned.

Not able to make jenkins create the second db also before starting the test. Please help.

Comment: I think you might have an error somewhere.

Comment: Without jenkins, the same code is running all the tests without any error. In Jenkins the error is when the second db is accessed. If I reverse db order in the settings.py, the db given first is created and the second one is not.

Comment: The issue was due to migration issues inside the workspace. Solved it by running the tests in a folder with post commit in svn to update the code on each commit. Had to do makemigrations on each app including auth.